# Integrate $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{\cos\theta} \sin(\sin\theta-n\theta)d\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

How to integrate

1. $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{\cos\theta} \sin(\sin\theta-n\theta)d\theta$
2. $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-\cos\theta} \cos(\sin\theta+n\theta)d\theta$

Comment: Any thoughts? $\ $

Comment: $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-\cos\theta} (\cos(\sin\theta+n\theta-i\sin(\sin\theta+n\theta))d\theta$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first integral is$$\Im\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\cos\theta+i(\sin\theta-n\theta)}d\theta=\Im\int_0^{2\pi}e^{e^{i\theta}-in\theta}d\theta.$$Expanding $e^{e^{i\theta}}$ as a power series in $e^{i\theta}$ and using $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{ik\theta}=2\pi\delta_{k0}$ for $k\in\Bbb Z$, this is$$\Im\frac{2\pi}{k!}=0.$$Similarly, the second integral is$$\Re\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-e^{-i\theta}+in\theta}d\theta=\frac{(-1)^n2\pi}{n!}.$$

Comment: i don't know how to use it on first question can you give me a proper solution please

Comment: @UdbhavaVarshney Hint: $\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{e^zdz}{z^{n+1}}$ is calculable by looking for the integrand's $\frac1z$ coefficient.

Comment: @UdbhavaVarshney I've edited my answer so it doesn't need any knowledge of the residue theorem. In this edit, $\delta_{k0}$ is a [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).